# How to get from a list<T> in C# from a document in MongoDB to

Tags: c#, mongodb

Here is my code:

```
    using MongoDB.Bson;
    using MongoDB.Driver;

    public List<Teacher> GetTeachersFromMongoDB()
    {
        client = new MongoClient();
        database = client.GetDatabase("SchoolManagement");
        var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("ListTeachers");
        var document = collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).ToList();
        var cursor = collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).ToCursor();
        return teachers;
    }
```

And i want to do something to return value type List for this function.
Please help me!!!
Thank you :)

Comment: Can't you just declare a new list then modify it and finally return? `List<Teacher> teachers = new List<Teacher>();` at the start of your GetTeachersFromMongoDB() function.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a Teacher object, so I think you should use

```
var collection = database.GetCollection<Teacher>("ListTeachers");
```

instead of

```
var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("ListTeachers");
```

And I don't get, where your return value comes from, but if you return 'document' it should work